# Matplotlib interface

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, interface, jupyter-notebook

I'm new in matplotlib and I have confusion on matplotlib interface. I'm reading pandas and matplotlib documentation and in the pandas one I read "the existing interface dataframe. Boxplot" (in a particular case). What does "existing interface" mean?

Here the link: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html

Thank you in advice!

Answer (score 0):

The "existing interface" is the syntax used for plotting which is `dataFrame.hist()`. The "new interface" is the newer syntax which is `dataframe.plot.hist()`.
They will have differences int heir functionality but both are usable to produce boxplots.